# AWS IAM Policy name is same as resource name defined in AWS Policy ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies

If i am generating a IAM policy using AWS policy generator as below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1628236330667",
      "Action": [
        "eks:CreateCluster",
        "eks:DescribeAddon",
        "eks:ListClusters"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:153012669680:policy/EKSFullAccess"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to give the policy name as EKSFullAccess or i can give any name to the policy?

Comment: That policy makes no sense, that resource is not a valid one, the resource needs to e.g. be a cluster. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am setting up EKS for the first time i want to create a policy and attach that to a role. Can you share the polcies needed for this configuration?

Comment: Do you want them to have permission to List all clusters and Describe all Addons? If so, set: `"Resource": "*"`

Comment: Might be relevant: [How to include AWS EKS with CI/CD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63878587/174777)